# How to force c3p0 statement to release all resources associated with resultset?

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures, c3p0

I'm trying to call Oracle stored procedure that returns implicit resultset from java application which uses Hibernate with c3p0 connection pool.
If statement pooling is enabled on c3p0 , every second invocation of stored procedure from the code throws SQLException with "ORA-01002 fetch out of sequence" message.  That happens only if c3p0 statement pooling is enabled; everything works fine otherwise.

Relevant piece of code :

```
return session.doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<List<Foo>>()
{
    @Override
    public List<Foo> execute(Connection connection)
        throws SQLException
    {
        C3P0ProxyConnection
            castCon = (C3P0ProxyConnection) ((JdbcWrapper<Connection>) connection).getWrappedObject();
        try(
            CallableStatement stmnt =castCon.prepareCall("call proc_implicit(?)");

        )
        {                                
            stmnt.setLong(1, 1L);                             
            stmnt.executeQuery();
            if (stmnt.getMoreResults())
            {

                List<Foo> retval = new ArrayList<>();
                try (ResultSet rs1 = stmnt.getResultSet())
                {                                        
                    while (rs1.next())
                    {
                        retval.add(FooResultSetConverter.fromResulSet(rs1));
                    }                                        
                }                                    
                return retval;
            }
        }
        return null;
    };
});
```

It seems that c3p0 pooling prevents proper resource releasing in such cases, so second `executeQuery()` throws an error, which in turn releases resources correctly thus allowing third execution to go through , and so on.

I wonder if it's possible to release ResultSet resources associated with Statement directly.   I tried `ResultSet.close()`, `CallableStatement.close()` to no avail (not surprisingly, connection pool must intercept and overwrite these calls ).

Surely, changing procedure to use `SYS_REFCURSOR` out parameter instead of returning results with `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` works, but I really like the idea of implicit resultsets.

Comment: It will be cold comfort to you that this "should" work. Sure, c3p0 intercepts calls to Statement and ResultSet.close(), but -- unconditionally for ResultSet -- it still closes the underlying resource. (For Prepared/CallableStatements, close() does not unconditionally destroy the underlying resource when Statement caching is enabled.) Given your use of try-with-resources, I'm not sure why things aren't working.

Comment: One thing you can do that you aren't meaningfully yet doing is unwrap the Connection + use it raw for this operation. Currently you use a helper I'm not familiar with to unwrap to Connection, which is not unwrapping at all, since you start w/an implementation of Connection. If you want the "naked" Connection + you know the name of yr driver's implementation class, consider using the standard [unwrap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/Wrapper.html) method to get to that. Or use c3p0's [raw Connection ops API](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#raw_connection_ops).

Comment: @SteveWaldman : Thanks, I tried raw operations; they didn't work in this case because "...Any Statements (including Prepared and CallableStatements) and ResultSets returned by raw operations will be c3p0-managed".

Comment: oh, right. but you can always do something like this if you want. 1) define in "MyClass" something like "public static Connection steal( Connection c ) { return c; }" 2) use "Method stealM = MyClass.class.getMethod( "steal", new Class[]{Connection.class} ); Connection rawConn = (Connection) c3p0ProxyConn.rawConnectionOperation( stealM, null, new Object[] {C3P0ProxyConnection.RAW_CONNECTION} );" Seems like a cheap trick, but nothing forbids it. On the contrary, it was left as a loophole for people who know what they're doing. (Sorry if I've screwed up, typing directly into comment box.)

Comment: the best thing to do, though, is just to use "Connection rawConn = c3p0Conn.unwrap( Connection.class );" i was wrong in my first comment that you need to know the type of the inner Connection. The unwrap method returns its wrapped object in preference to itself if both implement the requested interface.